# What is the RabbitMQ message max size can stored?

Tags: rabbitmq

We are uploading 23 mb text file RabbitMQ. We will convert that file to filestream and then we will bind that message to JSONObject.

```
 var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
            var excelFile = new FileInfo(path);
            FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            // Added Code for CommandComponent changes Start
            byte[] fileMessage = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(fileMessage, 0, fileMessage.Length);
            stream.Close();
            TempData["FileMessage"] = fileMessage;
            TempData["FileType"] = fileType;
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            // Added Code for CommandComponent changes End
            return Json(new { Result = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

By `AMQP` specification there is not limit. The body is a buffer where you can put what you prefer.

Obviously there is the network between your application and RabbitMQ and you can't send a big-file just with a simple send.

you have to implement some kind of the streaming